# how to explicitly create a new user in KeyStone.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, keystonejs

I am trying to modify keyStone.js project to match my requirements,i am having problems adding a new user from the server side

```
var User = keystone.list('User');
User.add({
 name: {first:"Abcd",
 last:"xyz" },
 email: "abc@xyz.com",
 password: "password",
 isAdmin: true
});
User.register();
```

But this isn't creating a new user in the MongoDB, any ideas what i maybe doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing up schema definition for `User` and creation of a `User`

This could be your schema definition in `models/User.js`:

```
var User = keystone.list('User');

User.add({
    name: { type: Types.Name, required: true, initial: true  },
    email: { type: Types.Email, required: true, initial: true },
    password: { type: Types.Password, required: true, initial: true },
    isAdmin: { type: Boolean },
});

User.register();
```

Then you can create a user like this:

```
var User = keystone.list('User').model;

var user = new User({
    name: { first:'Abcd', last:'xyz' },
    email: 'abc@xyz.com',
    password: 'password',
    isAdmin: true
});

user.save(function (err) {
    if (err) {
        // handle error
        return console.log(err);
    }

    // user has been saved
    console.log(user);
});
```